# Jquery - Restore Changed Placeholder?

Tags: jquery, placeholder, restore

I know how to change a placeholder, but how do I change it back if needed ?

I've tried this but it didn't change it back..

```
$('[name^="u_"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).next("input, select").attr("disabled",true);
        $(this).next("input, select").attr("placeholder", "New Holder");

    } else {
        $(this).next("input, select").attr("disabled",false);
        $(this).next("input, select").attr('defaultValue') 
    }
});
```

I'm using this code on multiple inputs. Each field has it's default placeholder set using :

```
<input type='checkbox' name='u_id'><input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ABC123">
```

Thanks .

Comment: Store the placeholder in a `data-placeholder` attribute? So you can restore it if needed

Comment: I'm rusty at jquery, so just a comment: as far as I rememember, `.attr()` always needs the attribute/property as first parameter, so the `.attr('defaultValue')` in the else case looks strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take another attribute for old placeholder like in my code I take `data-placeholder` which hold old value when you want it can be used as old placeholder.

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' name='u_id'>
<input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ABC123" data-placeholder="ABC123">
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[name^="u_"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).next("input, select").attr("disabled",true);
        $(this).next("input, select").attr("placeholder", "New Holder");

    } else {
        old_place_holder = $(this).next("input, select").attr("data-placeholder");
        $(this).next("input, select").attr("disabled",false);
        $(this).next("input, select").attr('placeholder',old_place_holder) ;
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tc4sfn8t/)**